# Input string is not in the correct format at the same time every day

Tags: wcf, iis-7

Built a client app that polls the WCF service hosted on IIS7 at timed intervals.  I cannot for the life of me understand why I get "Input string is not in the correct format" error at the exact same minute every day, i.e. 4:50am.  Checked Event Viewer, nothing there...  Is it the SQL Server, VM, network or...?

Here's the error and the StackTrace:

> ```
> Input string was not in a correct format.  
> Server stack trace:     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
> reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
> FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
> operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at 
>     System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)    at
> MyApplication.GenericService.IGenericService.GetCommands(String
> fileName, CompanyCredentials credentials, String sequence)    at
> MyApplication.GenericService.GenericServiceClient.GetCommands(String
> fileName, CompanyCredentials credentials, String sequence)    at
> MyApplication.ApplicationClass.RunCommands(String sequence)
> ```

Comment: What was the string you tried to input and into what?

Comment: It varies between different methods but only at 4:50am, I trap the error and re-run the method a few seconds later, it's fine.  I'll probably have to add some logging as to exactly what parameters I am passing to the method.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that you could check:

- Are you sending a date time as a string, and there is a diffence in the time format betweem the macines?
- Is recycling of app pool run just before 4:50 so that the first call after recyling allways fails
- How are the credentials being sent? Have the credentials expired?

Comment: 1. all machines are in the same office so no chance for datetime differential  2. app pool recycles the default 29 hours (1740 minutes) so doesn't explain the same time daily.  3. I pass credentials for every service call so expiration not possible.